# Dynamically expand dictionary variables in Ansible

Tags: dictionary, ansible, expand

I'm trying to unify the way I install packages, I have the following

```
vars/main.yml:
---
packages:
  system:
    common:
      - crudini
      - dump
      - duplicity
      - git
      - mdadm
      - irssi
      - lynx
      - postfix
      - powerline
      - rsync
      - tmux
      - vim
    Debian:
      - ntp
    Fedora:
      - langpacks-en
      - langpacks-nl
      - livecd-tools
      - rktime
      - tmux-powerline
      - tuned
      - vim-powerline
```

And the following task:

```
- name: install ansible dependencies
  package: name={{ item }} state=present
  with_flattened:
    - "{{ packages.system.common }}"
    - "{{ packages.system.Fedora }}"
    - "{{ vars['packages.system.' + ansible_distribution] }}"
  when: ansible_distribution == "Fedora"
  tags:
    install_custom2
```

Which results in the following error:

```
TASK [common : install ansible dependencies] *******************************************************************************************
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute u'packages.system.Fedora'"}
```

Please note that the `"{{ packages.system.Fedora }}"`  works fine but the `"{{ vars['packages.system.' + ansible_distribution] }}"` fails (which expands to `packages.system.Fedora` as well). It looks like a type error. When I organize the package names in vars/main.yml as separate lists, it does work. But I would like to create this dictionary structure since it organizes the variables nicely. Is there a way to expand dictionary variables dynamically just like list variables?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it works with: `"{{ packages.system[ansible_distribution] }}"`